# MySql update only when field null

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement to update a users cash, however I want this to only actually update when the second field `fqdate` is null, the below however is not working:

`UPDATE users SET cash = (cash+' . $rewardCash . '), fqdate = now() WHERE userid = ? AND ISNULL(fqdate)`

Comment: isnull returns the first non-value in the series of 2.  It's not a function returning true/false.   so isnull(fqdate) will return null if fqdate is null.  since and null means nothing to the database; it would fail.  you need to use and fqdate is null so that only fqdates that are null have the possibility of being updated.

Answer (score 1):

What about `UPDATE users SET cash = (cash+' . $rewardCash . '), fqdate = now() WHERE userid = ? AND fqdate IS NULL`